# OrmLite can create table successfully but cause error after insert a record

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

In my project I used OrmLite to create a table named OrderItem, in logcat it create table successfully but when I try to insert a record it show an exception. I would like to know why this is happening? Please my logcat.

Thanks

After create OrderItem

```
09-12 07:30:13.075: I/TableUtils(22428): creating table 'OrderItem'

09-12 07:30:13.085: I/TableUtils(22428): executed create table statement changed 1 rows: CREATE TABLE `OrderItem` (`custom_taste` VARCHAR , `order_id` INTEGER , `name` VARCHAR , `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT , `food_id` INTEGER , `quantity` INTEGER )
```

After insert a record to OrderItem it show food_id column not found. In above logcat food_id column is created.

```
09-12 07:32:00.885: E/SQLiteLog(22428): (1) table OrderItem has no column named food_id

09-12 07:32:00.905: W/System.err(22428): java.sql.SQLException: Unable to run insert stmt on object com.expresspos.mm.object.OrderItem@40ddbdd8: INSERT INTO `OrderItem` (`custom_taste` ,`order_id` ,`name` ,`food_id` ,`quantity` ) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: I have omitted to add a condition in my question, the column name food_id is added in OrderItem.java after I have been creating a database.

Answer (score 0):

While I am waiting for somebody's answer, I searched some solution to my qestion. This link is helpful https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ormlite-android/k-i1MnaL-aQ.

Here is my solution,

```
 // some set of alter table statements to tweak the schema
orderItemDao.executeRaw("ALTER TABLE `OrderItem` ADD COLUMN food_id INTEGER DEFAULT 0;");
```

I didn't think about that I need to alter OrderItem table when adding a column. I have to alter table because that database I have preferred is already been created.

Thanks